# What time does the train from Yerevan arrive in Tbilisi?

Tags: trains, georgia-country, tbilisi, armenia, yerevan

Two friends of mine told me they were taking the train yesterday from Yerevan, which would travel overnight, and arrive today in Tbilisi.

Unfortunately they didn't tell me what time the train is expected to arrive!

Now official train timetables in this part of the world seem to be hard to find at least if you can only search in English. Searching generally I find somewhat consistent answers in forums on travelling in the opposite direction from Georgia to Armenia, but the information for this direction seems to be out of date. I am told trains leave from Yerevan on even days of the month but I'm not sure this is current as others have told me there is a day train and a night train and the most current online answer I can find, from September 2011, [even states the train is not overnight](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=2101710):

> The last option can be the train that leaves Yerevan at 3.00 pm and reaches Tbilisi at 11.00 pm.

**So what is the current timetable for trains from Yerevan Armenia to Tbilisi Georgia as of March 2012?**

Answer (score 7):

From the [official timetable](http://www.railway.ge/?web=1&action=page&p_id=479&lang=eng) of Georgian Railways.

There is a train #202/201 Tbilisi - Yerevan which leaves at 8:20pm and arrives 7am. This train leaves Tbilisi on odd dates such as was yesterday and when you have 31 days in a month skips the 1st. This train will go back the next day such today leaving Yerevan at 10 pm and arriving to Tbilisi at 9 am

**EDITED**

[There is a schedule](http://www.ukzhd.am/raspisanie.html) if you can Google Translate it from Russian.  It states that train to Tbilisi arrives at 9am.  There is no indication from the page that this train doesn't run every day.  So it is quite likely that it is.

Comment: Sorry Karlson, I'm asking about Yerevan to Tbilisi, not Tbilisi to Yerevan. Also Armenia and Azerbaijan have been bitter enemies since the break up of the USSR and there is no train between them now. At least part of the train line at Yerevan has even been removed and a road is now in that place. However you can get between Baku and Yerevan by train if you change at Tbilisi.

Comment: @hippietrail Sorry .  Corrected my answer.

Comment: Aha this seems to be the link I needed: [Georgian Railway / Traffic General Schedule](http://www.railway.ge/?web=1&action=page&p_id=479&lang=eng)

Comment: @hippietrail Such beautiful places and such as political zoo.  I edited the answer but I have some issue with proxies where I am.

Comment: On the various russian and other forums there are mentions of buses, marshrutkas, and taxis between the cities.

Comment: It turns out my friends weren't aware of the even/odd date thing so couldn't come by train after all and instead arrived much later by bus or marshrutka, but the QA is still valuable for the future since it's not easy to find the answers.

Answer (score 3):

The train runs from Tbilisi on odd days of the month and from Yerevan on even ones.