# Possibilities to travel from Yerevan to Batumi

Tags: transportation, georgia-country, armenia, batumi, yerevan

What are the possibilities to get from Yerevan to Batumi?

Is there any direct option?

How long does it takes and how much does it cost?

Comment: This is basically a combination of 2 questins: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6105/what-time-does-the-train-from-yerevan-arrive-in-tbilisi?rq=1, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5932/what-time-do-buses-and-or-marshrutkas-leave-from-tbilisi-for-batumi?rq=1, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7217/trains-between-tbilisi-and-batumi?rq=1

Comment: Yes, of course, but these were asked 2 years ago.

Comment: Most links and schedules are still valid today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides taking the train as @Karlson points out, there are also multiple daily connections by minivan between Yerevan and Tbilisi. I think this took about 7 hours last time I did the journey.

Then, from Tbilisi there are trains and buses that can take you to Batumi. I seem to remember there are overnight trains, but a bus is much faster.

I don't remember the cost.

I also don't think there are direct connections between Yerevan and Batumi.